# routerLink error in child route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, single-page-application

I have a parent component (profile) and in this component i have Basket route (profile / basket) , this is my Basket component :

```
export class basket extends Ext implements OnDestroy{

    private ShopItems_Movies  : Array<{}> = [];
    private ShopItems_Music   : Array<{}> = [];
    subscriptions : Subscription[] = [];


    constructor(private _util: UtilService,private _shareService : shareService , private _Router : Router){
        super();

        this.subscriptions.push(_shareService.ShopItemSS$_.subscribe((items) =>{

            console.log(items);
            this.ShopItems_Movies = this.ext.givemelist(items ,{_type : "video"});
            this.ShopItems_Music  = this.ext.givemelist(items ,{_type : "music"});


        }));

    }


}
```

and my template :

```
    <a [routerLink]="[item._type == 'video' ? 'Watch' : 'Listen', {uuid: item.item.uuid}]" class="btn-block right-align">
           <div class="circle item_small_like_icon2 background_standard middle inline-block" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + _util.storageUrl(item.item.thumbnail)  + ')'}">
   </div>
      <p class="black-text right-align middle inline-block margin-right-5">{{item.title}}</p>
  </a>
```

and parent route config :

```
@RouteConfig([


     {name: 'Basket', component: basket ,path: '/basket' }
])
```

my problem is when i want use `[routerLink]` in basket template throw this erorr : `platform-browser.umd.js:962 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component "basket" has no route config.`
i dont have any child in basket!!have another child component and routeLink without any problem its ok in that templates!but in this component i cant find my problem!

Comment: please post your parent component routing code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar question already today where it worked this way:

```
<a [routerLink]="item._type == 'video' ? ['Watch', {uuid: item.item.uuid}] : ['Listen', {uuid: item.item.uuid}]" class="btn-block right-align">
```

Comment: Um, not sure. Would need a Plunker to reproduce.

Comment: You could try `../Watch` instead of `Watch` but without a Plunker to reproduce it's hard to tell.

Comment: shiiiitttt!!!! its worked :DDDD but use `../../Watch` tnxxxx again...you answer my all questions :)))))